# In PySpark, what's the exact value of lambda x,y in the processing of `rdd.reduce(lambda x,y:x+y)`?

Tags: pyspark, lambda, rdd

For example,

```
rdd=sc.parallelize(range(5),5)
rdd.reduce(lambda x,y:x+y)
```

Then what's the exact value of lambda x,y in the processing?
I assume that we can just process one value when there is an array as an input. But lambda get two values.

Sorry I can't print it as usual in python.

Comment: it works the same as python's native `reduce`. for a list of 3 nums -- `[1, 2, 3]` -- in the first iteration, x=1 & y=2 -- it gets added and the result becomes the new x for second iteration with new y as 3. in short, it is `((1+2)+3)`.

Comment: first iteration should be x = 0, y = 1.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I know how it works now.
But this kind of way of work is not so common I think. We can't see how it works from the surface of lambda expression. A little bit weird thing, I never see something like that in other using of lambda expression.. ( if there are some example more about something similar to it, it's more appreciated) ??? ( just for marked to future study )